# HTML 5 Panotour Pro implementation

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, html, panoramas

I cannot find any information regarding on what to write to display my virtual tour exclusively in HTML 5. Anyone?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question. This seems very vague to me.

Comment: Well don't mark it down just because it seems vague to you. It's really all I need to ask, but to elaborate, there's a script to implement the Flash viewer that is generated automatically by Panotour Pro. Panotour does not, to my knowledge, generate anything for the HTML 5 viewer. So, I need that script.

Answer (score 2):

panotour pro does output HTML5 panoramas, just not in the demo trial version

panotour pro is basically just a GUI for KRPano, which actually creates the flash + html5 panorama

see here for info on krpano & html5 + flash panoramas

http://krpano.com/docu/html5/

pano2vr also can output html5 + flash panoramas

http://gardengnomesoftware.com/wiki/Pano2VR_-_HTML5_Export

Answer (score 0):

I found a display of the HTML5 version, view source, and found this links.

http://ptp.panopress.org/test/

More information on this link: http://www.panopress.org/forum/discussion/90/panotour-pro-panopress-instructions/p1

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://ptp.panopress.org/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ptp.panopress.org/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://ptp.panopress.org/wp-content/plugins/panopress/css/panopress.css" />    
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ptp.panopress.org/wp-content/plugins/panopress/js/panopress.js"></script>
```

Comment: Something that confuses me here are the CSS files. Where do those come from? Panotour does not generate those. This needs to work without an internet connection.

Comment: The css is only to style it and have it show up in the right spot on the page for the layout. You do not need the CSS if you are already doing that in HTML.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong javascript file? I'm using krpanoiphone.js. Besides that, all I have is the license.

Comment: I just see a blank screen. Nothing loads.

Comment: In Panotour Pro's tour build settings I have mobile devices tour checked, html template set to none and pictures export on auto.

Comment: Please help.. there are no other javascript files. What do I do?

Comment: I am not sure, the test works for me on my iPad, but I cant really say what is wrong.

Comment: Does anyone have a clue why this won't work? I've tried smaller images (2000 px width) which just makes black space around it and has a warning symbol.  At that point I can't even publish to mobile probably because of the warning. I didn't think it would be this frustrating just to have this program output to HTML5.

Comment: It works in Safari if I change the user agent to iPad, but not on my iPad itself.  Could the image size of the pano be a problem? Mine is 3290 × 1024.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this may have to do more with displaying html with images, etc in my resources folder locally, and not on the web. It works fine on iPad's Safari when uploading it to the web.  The Kolor forums suggested I should use Goodreader to experience the least problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PTP 2.+ then you simply change the Build / Output settings to only use "html5"...see screenshot @ https://panoramus.co.uk/ptp2_output_settings.jpg

I would recommend outputting in flash + html5 and forcing the browser to choose html5, this can be done by appending **&html5=only** to tour link / embed code as shown in link below.
http://krpano.com/krpano.html?xml=tours/corfu/tour.xml&html5=only

If you view the page source for above tour sample, you can see it only loads flash if html5 is not supported.

Hopes his helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of PTP you can select/deselect
- html5
- flash
- ptv (Offline ptp viewer format)

So can choose just what you want?